# Following the Hardhat tutorial, I get this error :TypeError: ethers.isAddressable is not a function

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am following Patrick Hardhat tutorial  Lesson13 : Hardhat Defi and aave and get this unexpected error:

```
const { getNamedAccounts ,ethers } = require("hardhat");
const AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.02");
async function getWeth(){
    const {deployer}  = await getNamedAccounts();
    const iWeth = await ethers.getContractAt("IWeth",deployer,"0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2");
    const tx = await iWeth.deposit({value : AMOUNT})
    await tx.await(1);
    const wethBalance = await iWeth.BalanceOf(deployer);
}
module.exports = {
    getWeth
}
```